# How to access a parent function in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that is a form, that when submitted, inserts into a database. And I need to re-list the data as it changed in the database. That method of listing is found in another component.
I tried with a viewChild to call the functions, but the ViewChild appears as undefined when I submit.

This is the data Component who list the data in the html

```
    export class DataComponent implements OnInit{  
      constructor(private dataService: DataService,private router:Router) {
            this.getData();
           }
        
          ngOnInit(): void {
          }
          getData(){
            this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
              resp => this.data = resp,
              error =>console.log(error)
            );
          }
          detail(id: number){
            this.router.navigate(['data/check' + id]);
          }
}
```

And this is the checkComponent who is the form.

```
export class CheckComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
      form: FormGroup;
      data: any = [];
      id: number;
      @ViewChildren(DataComponent) dataComponent: DataComponent ;
      constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private dataService: DataService
      ) {
         this.id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
          this.Service.getReporte(this.id).subscribe(
            (resp: any) => this.data = resp,
            (error) => console.log(error)
          );
        }
      }
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.makeForm();
      }
     makeForm() {
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
          ...
        });
      }
    
    sendData() {
        const data = {
                  ...    
         };
          this.dataService.createData(data).subscribe(
            (resp) => console.log(resp),
            (error) => console.log(error)
          );
          this.dataComponent.getData(); //undefined
          this.router.navigate(['data']);
        }
    
      }
```

Is there a way to call the functions of another component besides ViewChild? Or am I implementing it wrong? I need to access the function **getData()** of the DataComponent

Comment: I think what you really need to do is put the logic in a service that can be called from any interested component, and use Observables so that each interested component receives updates when they need them.

Comment: P.S. Trying to call another component's function is, as far as I know, impossible, and is in any case an Angular anti-pattern, i.e. something to be avoided even if it is possible.

Comment: since you are using router navigate, after loading data component it will call getdata method after route so you can remove 'this.dataComponent.getData();' from your form component

Answer (score 0):

If DataComponent is a child of CheckComponent, my recommendation would be to use a top down approach/one-way data binding to the data flow. That is:

- Track the main data object in a property on CheckComponent
- Add an input on DataComponent that accepts the main data object.

When the data is updated on CheckComponent, change detection occurs. This will pass the updated data DOWN to DataComponent, which will automatically update its view.

This is the correct approach for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewChildren` gives you a `QueryList`, not a single instance of the component.

```
import {QueryList} from '@angular/core';

...

ViewChildren(DataComponent) dataComponent: QueryList<DataComponent>;
```

is the proper typing... `QueryList` API shares a lot of functions with the js array API, and lets you do this...

```
this.dataComponent.forEach(dc => dc.getData());
```

`QueryList` docs: https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList

`ViewChild` would give you the first instance of the child component on the page

```
ViewChild(DataComponent, {static: false}) dataComponent: DataComponent;
```

this would let you access your `DataComponent` as you have in your question, if you only have / want one.